# How to set the configuration of a plugin correctly in Errbot?

Tags: python, plugins, configuration, errbot

I try to follow the sample given by the documentation:

[9.1. Plugin configuration through the built-in !config command](http://errbot.io/en/latest/user_guide/plugin_development/configuration.html#plugin-configuration-through-the-built-in-config-command)

However, I do not manage in getting back the configuration of the plugin which is set to `'NoneType'`

```
[@admin ➡ @errbot] >>> !plugin config Samples
Default configuration for this plugin (you can copy and paste this directly as a command):
 !plugin config Samples
{'ID_TOKEN': '00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff', 'USERNAME': 'changeme'}


[@admin ➡ @errbot] >>> !mycommand
Computer says nooo. See logs for details:
 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

[@admin ➡ @errbot] >>> !about
This is Errbot version 5.2.0
```

This is my plugin code `sample.py`

```
from errbot import BotPlugin, botcmd

class Samples(BotPlugin):
    """Samples of plugins from Errbot documentation"""

    # 9. Configuration
    # 9.1. Plugin configuration through the built-in !config command
    def get_configuration_template(self):
        return {'ID_TOKEN': '00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff',
                'USERNAME':'changeme'}

    @botcmd
    def mycommand(self, mess, args):
        # oh I need my TOKEN !
        token = self.config['ID_TOKEN']
```

I am not sure if it is a bug or a bad configuration.

**Solution**

I had to call once the configuration given

```
[@admin ➡ @errbot] >>> !plugin config Samples {'ID_TOKEN' : '00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff', 'USERNAME':'changeme'}
Plugin configuration done.

[@admin ➡ @errbot] >>> !mycommand
00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff
```

@gbin Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the config command with the json config, here errbot just tells you what you need to do to configure it.